# Java Printing Hashcode instead of Content

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, hashcode

I am trying to iterate inside some arrays containing the name, last name, id and the score of some student. I have to sort this array in descending format. I have used comparable function and compare the elements according to their scores. This is my code:
`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    private static class Student {
        String fName; // First Name
        String lName; // Last Name
        int id; // Student ID
        int score; // Score

        public Student(String fName, String lName, int id, int score) {
            this.fName = fName;
            this.lName = lName;
            this.id = id;
            this.score = score;
        }
            public int getScore() {
                return score;
            }
        }


//      Checking if Alphabetic or not
    public static boolean alphabetic(String str) {
        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
        for (char c : charArray) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(c))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of students");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k = input.nextInt(); // number of students
        Student[] students = new Student[k];
        for (int i = 0; i < k; ) {
            System.out.println("Enter id");
            int id = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter first name ");
            String fName = input.next();
            while (alphabetic(fName)== false){
                System.out.println("Wrong! Please enter again ");
            }
            System.out.println("Enter last name ");
            String lName= input.next();
            while (alphabetic(lName)==false) {
                System.out.println("Wrong! Please enter again ");
            }
            System.out.println("Enter score ");
            int score = input.nextInt();

            students[i++] = new Student(fName, lName, id, score);

        }

         class ByScoreComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
            @Override public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
                return Integer.compare(s1.getScore(), s2.getScore());
            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(students, new ByScoreComparator());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students));
```

`

I know that for changing the hashcode, I have to use toString() method but even though I use this method, I still get the hashcodes instead of the values. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use toString() method for an Object you should redefine it at the Object class.

So, you need to add this part of code at Student Class :

```
@Override
    public String toString(){
        return "id: "+this.id + " " + "fName: " + this.fName + " " + "lName: " + this.lName + " " + "score: " + this.score;
    }
```

And the result is printed as needed :

```
[id: 2 fName: Lee lName: Jen score: 600, id: 1 fName: Mo lName: Nee score: 900]
```